# Searching for questions that have one of two tags.

Tags: support, tagging, search

How can I search for two tags at once?
For example, search for all questions that are tagged with either [set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory) or [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory).

Answer (score 4):

Search for:

> [tag1] or [tag2]

or for

> [tag1] [or] [tag2]

The or are inclusive.

If you want tag1 yet not also tag2:

> [tag1] -[tag2]

As you certainly remarked just giving several tags is taken as 'and'.

One can combine these operators to get more complex queries but for too complex queries SEDE is likely better.

For some more details see 
[How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-or-without-specific-tags)

Comment: Could I specialize the posted question even more?  your [tag1]-[tag2] will help (is there supposed to be a space after [tag1] and the - sign?).  How does one search one's own questions (separately, one's own answers to questions) tagged [tag1] but not [tag2].  I'm assuming one would need, e.g., in my case to somehow use user:9003 (or one's username?) along with syntax to indicate whether one is looking for all of one's questions (or answers), plus [tag1]-[tag2]?  (Sorry, I can do basic searches but have trouble with more complicated searches...

Comment: ... e.g. "I want a list of all my answers to questions with the tag [abstract-algebra], but **not** with the tag [group-theory]."

Comment: Though tag or tag works, when I select newest I don't get the newest questions.  I am using that with answers:0.  I am using answers:0 to limit my use of MSE because the new  MSE is harder to use.  If the left side colume of little worth, were made a fixed header with an option for a floating header for those who just have to have it instantly, then the much prefered two colume layout could be restored.

Comment: @amWhy yes user:theusernumber works to restrict the search; for oneself  user:me works.For the specific one you can use `user:me [abstract-algebra] -[group-theory]` There must be no space *after* the minus, one before is not (at least not always) needed but it is normalized to that.

Comment: Thank you, @quid.  So commas cannot be used as separators? e.g. `user:me, [abstract-algebra] -[group-theory]`?  Or are such commas just ignored?

Comment: @amWhy space serves as separator there is no need for a comma. Commas sometimes seem to be ignored and could be used as a separator, but not always. I do not know the exact rules.

Comment: That's good to know.  I had grown so used to "comma separated" fields for search; and perhaps some of my failures searching on MSE have been due to that, in some cases.

Comment: @WilliamElliot what else do you get?  Are you sure you selected "newest" after the search? Can you post a screen-shot of the incorrect result?

Comment: It is much simpler live without 'or' than to chase out this bug.  It is not making an annoying buzz unlike that new Big Bug.